# Doubts about NetworkExtension iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been using NetworkExtension and I am having some doubts, and need help.
In my entitlements is set:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.networking.HotspotHelper</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.external-accessory.wireless-configuration</key>
<true/>
```

I set in the Info.plist:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
<string>network-authentication</string>
</array>
```

In my controller I coded:

```
NSArray * networkInterfaces = [NEHotspotHelper supportedNetworkInterfaces];
NSLog(@"Networks %@",networkInterfaces);
```

But the return is nil.

I also tried register NEHotspotHelp, and after I have used  [NEHotspotHelper supportedNetworkInterfaces]  but return only the network connected.

```
NSMutableDictionary* options = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[options setObject:@"Hotspot" forKey:kNEHotspotHelperOptionDisplayName];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp.wifi", 0);
BOOL returnType = [NEHotspotHelper registerWithOptions:options queue:queue handler: ^(NEHotspotHelperCommand * cmd) {
}];
 NSArray * networkInterfaces = [NEHotspotHelper supportedNetworkInterfaces];
 NSLog(@"Networks %@",networkInterfaces);
```

**Is possible list nearby networks in my application, without enter in the screen of Settings/Wifi?**

**When use [NEHotspotHelper supportedNetworkInterfaces] may I list all nearby networks?**

Thanks a lot.

Michel de Sousa

Comment: Hi Michel de Sousa, have you got this resolved? Please post the solution if Yes.

Comment: Yes Yogi, but is need enter in the screen of Settings/Wi-fi.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved my problem, but is need enter in the screen of Settings/Wi-fi.

I listed nearby network in my application using:

```
NSMutableDictionary* options = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[options setObject:@"Connect using my app" forKey:kNEHotspotHelperOptionDisplayName];
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp.wifi", 0);
[NEHotspotHelper registerWithOptions:optionsqueue:queue handler: ^(NEHotspotHelperCommand * cmd) {
if(cmd.commandType == kNEHotspotHelperCommandTypeFilterScanList){
    for (NEHotspotNetwork *eachNetwork in cmd.networkList) {
        // Get Informations of the network
        NSLog(@"%@", eachNetwork.SSID);
    }
}
}];
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked but is it a bug or what. There is no mention about the requirement to navigate the Setting -> Wi-fi section in the documentation. Could you please consider answering http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41095687/call-to-nehotspothelper-register-never-returns. I will accept the answer.